# Eclipse error: No source available for ""

Tags: eclipse, debugging, assembly

Using Eclipse Helios in Mac OS X Leopard and debugging C++ code calling fsf gdb 7.1, the debugging stops at first line of main. Then after the first step I get

```
No source available for ""
View disassembly
```

Why this error? Should I give additional options for compilation? Eclipse generated automatically the Makefile

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem and the following solved it:

Go to menu `Run->Debug Configurations...` and a dialogue window opens. On the left there should be selected your project name (say *MyProject* for example) under `C/C++ Application`. If not select it. Then on the right side, select the tab `main` and make sure that in the textbox under `C/C++ Application` reads: *Debug/MyProject*. Also check that *Debug* is selected in the dropdown box next to `Build Configuration:` below.

In my case instead of *Debug/MyProject*, it was *Release/MyProject*. I never understood why. Anyway...

Hope that helps