# Int to float conversion on STM32F4

Tags: c, types

I have to write the function that calculates the inverse matrix. Using eclipse there is no problem, but when i'm trying to run the code on STM32F4 it throws: No source available for "__floatsisf() " while proceeding the line:

```
    C->data[i][j] = -2.0*((float)((i+j)%2)-0.5)*DetMatrix(&M[i][j])/det;
```

I've also tried:

```
    C->data[i][j] = -2.0*(fmod((float)((i+j)),2.0)-0.5)*DetMatrix(&M[i][j])/det;
```

But it have ended with the same result. Can you give me some advise how to solve that problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219081/eclipse-error-no-source-available-for