# Weird errors in Eclipse and C++

Tags: c++

I'm truly hopeless now.
I'm getting these weird errors when running my uni project due very soon and can't seem to get anywhere.
For example, I'm trying to read a txt file using fscanf and it fails giving the weirds error.
Here's the code:

```
fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        if (df == 1)
            printf("The default configuration file spcbir.config couldn't be open\n");
        else
            printf("The configuration file %s couldn't be open\n", filename);

        *msg = SP_CONFIG_CANNOT_OPEN_FILE;
        return NULL;
    }
    result = (SPConfig) malloc (sizeof(SPConfig));
    if (result == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory Allocation Error");
        fclose(fp);
        *msg =  SP_CONFIG_ERROR;
        return NULL;
    }
    fillDefaults(result);
    str = "";
    element = "";
    value = "";
    while (fscanf (fp, "%s\n", str) != 0)
```

It fails on the last line giving this as an error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQbeK.jpg

Please help, this is only the first error out of many Im dealing with.

Comment: You should put the error message in text here and not as a screenshot. Also have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219081/eclipse-error-no-source-available-for

Comment: `result = (SPConfig) malloc (sizeof(SPConfig));`? can you post the full code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219081/eclipse-error-no-source-available-for

Comment: what's the relation with eclipse?? this isn't even C++

Comment: The full code seems probably a bit too much. This also seems like a problem when starting the debugger. Not necessarily when running the code. So this would be an eclipse setting problem I guess

Comment: What is SPConfig? What's the implementation of fillDefaults?

Comment: Heyguys thanks for the quick reply. I've viewed that post and it still not working. The main of the project is in cpp all the rest are c but the compiler is still cpp I guess

Comment: the SPConfig struct is one of the structs we were asked to implement and indeed it is too long to share but It's not relevant. I wonder why a simple command as fscanf and fgets are not working

Comment: have you tried running the code outside of eclipse? just starting the binary on a command line? The error you see is most likely just the debugger telling you it does not know the source of some internal function. Can you just ignore it and continue?

Comment: Unfortunately when its trying to process fscan it fails and the program crashes. I've tried ignoring it and make a test case of SPConfig but than I get stuck later on with another class so I'm trying to solve this first

Comment: I ran the executable with the command line and gdb and got this error on the same line of fscanf: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x7712ecfb in ungetwc () from C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll

Comment: what is `str`? Is it a `std::string` or a `const char*`? Both can not be used in `fscanf`.

Comment: I've defined it like this: char* str;

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
result = (SPConfig) malloc (sizeof(SPConfig));
```

is definitely fishy. Assuming `SPConfig` is a pointer type, you are allocating memory large enough to hold a pointer not necessarily large enough to hold an object.

You need to use:

```
result = (SPConfig) malloc (sizeof(*result));
```

or better yet (since you are in C++ land),

```
result = new <<the object type>>;
```

Comment: Correct. I've fixed that. but still no go on the fscanf

Comment: @doria90, that points to problem(s) in other parts of your code. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I can't post a comment, but this probably is not solution for your problem, but just a guess as I don't see full code. You mentioned that you defined str like:

```
char* str;
```

Then you point the str to an empty memory for "" (i.e. buffer with just 1 byte: \0). Better would be to allocate space for str:

```
char str[80];   // or whatever size you need
```

and instead of

```
str = "";
```

you should just clear the space allocated:

```
memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));
```

Or just use C++ and std::getline() to read from a file stream.